# downloadHandler in shiny in a loop

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app to retrieve data from an Oracle table based on user specified ID. I want to create one file with data for each ID and download it to the default downloads folder. I would also like to zip the files and provide the user with that one file. Also, the app is just to download the data and I really don't want a main Panel hence the width of the mainPanel is zero. If that's not the way to do it, please let me know.The app is going to reside on a server and hence the need for a download Handler. Below is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(ROracle)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  useShinyalert(),

   # Application title
  titlePanel(fluidRow(
    column(10, "RAINFALL AND ET DATA RETRIEVAL",align="center"),
    column(2, offset = 0,img(height =90,width=250,src="logo.png",align="left"))

  )),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width = 12,
                   helpText("Please enter IDs separated by commas. You can enter up to 25 IDs."),
                   textInput("PixelID", "Pixel ID(s)", value = ""), 


                   helpText("OR"),


                   fileInput('datafile','Choose csv file to upload Pixel IDs.The csv file should have Pixel IDs in the first column WITHOUT ANY HEADER.',accept = c('csv','comma-separated-values','.csv')),

                   helpText("Please select a parameter you would like to retrieve."),
                   radioButtons("ParameterType", "Parameters",
                                choices = c("Rainfall Estimates","Evapotranspiration Estimates"),
                                selected = "None"),
dateInput("startdate","Data From", format = "yyyy-mm-dd",max = Sys.Date()),
                                    dateInput("enddate","Data To", format = "yyyy-mm-dd",max = Sys.Date()),
br(), br(),
                   actionBttn("goButton","Go!",color = "default",style = "fill",size = "lg"),
                   br(),br(),
                   uiOutput("download"),
mainPanel(width=0)
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data<-eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    if(is.null(input$PixelID) || input$PixelID == ""){
      req(input$datafile)
      infile<-input$datafile
      PixelList<-read.table(infile$datapath, header = FALSE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      colnames(PixelList)<-"PixelNum"
      PixelList_comma<-paste(PixelList$PixelNum, collapse = ",")} else{
        if(input$PixelID != ""){
          PixelList<-data.frame(strsplit(input$PixelID,","))
          colnames(PixelList)<-"PixelNum"
          PixelList_comma<-input$PixelID
        }}

    drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")

    connection <- dbConnect(drv, username = "xxxx", password = "xxxxx", dbname = "xxxx")

    if(input$ParameterType=="Rainfall Estimates"){



        for(i in 1:nrow(PixelList)){
          raindata<-dbGetQuery(connection, paste("select PIXEL, TO_CHAR(tsdatetime_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as DATE_TIME, tsvalue_ms as RAINFALL from xxxx
                            where feature_id =",PixelList[i,1]," order by tsdatetime_dt", sep=""))  
        }

        dbDisconnect(conn = connection)


    }
    return(raindata)


  })
output$download <- renderUI({

    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")




  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("testnexrad",".zip",sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      for(i in 1:nrow(PixelList)){
     #No idea what to do here   


      }

    }
  ) 
}




# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```